# I cannot seem to get routing to work for my controller using Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-routing

My controller works when I use the ng-controller attribute to my template-less code, and with routing my template loads, but not the controller. I cannot seem to find what I missed.

Error message:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'OpListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

This is my app and route js. the OpLists var is a server submitted var, so at the moment it populates when the page loads.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var appid = 'app';
    var app = angular.module(appid, [

        'ngAnimate',        // animations
        'ngRoute',          // routing

    ]);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', buildRoute]);

    function buildRoute($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/op',{
            templateUrl: OpLists, //'app/op/Lists.html',
            controller: 'OpListCtrl',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/op'
        })
    }

    //Make sure the template (OpList) is correct.
    console.log("SetRoute: " + OpLists);

})();
```

Here is my controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'opListCtrl';

    // TODO: replace app with your module name
    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$scope', '$http', CreateOpListCtrl]);

    function CreateOpListCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.title = controllerId;

        $http.get(ApiOpList, { method: 'GET', responseType: 'json' })
            .success(function (data) { $scope.OpLists = data; });

   }

})();
```

directory for this is
root
--app
----op

If it wasn't for the fact that my controller works without routing, I would have focused on the controller. And since routing is loading my template, I am confused as to how it could be the routing. So I am blatantly missing something that I just cannot see..

Comment: Looks like it's just a typo- OpListCtrl (in your route provider) vs opListCtrl (as declared)

Comment: That was it. I spent hours looking for that typo. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KayakDave found my typo. Where as I spent hours on it.